# What's happen about my ConstraintLayout why I am running?

Tags: android

everyone
I am a beginner. I tried to use `ConstraintLayout` with Android studio 3.1.1 and  genymotion. when I run the project on genymotion emulator, It is different from what I have coded. Images FYI.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where is your code?

Answer (score 0):

For Constrain Layout, You can to pull all point from the box of your `TextView` (for example)to top, bottom, left and right to remain it in the position. It could takes sometimes if have lots of `button` or `textView` or what so ever.

**ConstrainLayout**

sampleCode

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.32" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: ConstrainLayout]

You have to pull the line from the dot of the box to everyside so it could stay at the position.

Since you are a beginner, I think You can consider `LinearLayout`.

As `LinearLayout`, it is align those `textView` and `button` or anything inside in arrangement. As long as You it in vertical or horizontal.

**Example**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
....
//Edit your layout
</LinearLayout>
```

Another good layout for beginner is `RelativeLayout`

`RelativeLayout` you can drag and drop the `textView` or `button` or what so ever to the layout.

**Example**

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
....
//Edit your layout
</RelativeLayout>
```

U have to keep edit and arrange until the design is what you like.

However, I believe there is a lot of tutorial You can learn from *Youtube*. Check it Out.

Answer (score 0):

Each component needs to be constrained to be able to display correctly. I think you should do it. Because some TextView components seem to have no constraints